# Zoom out is stuck in achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

Below is the issue: We have a Line chart with zoom and pan enabled using achartengine library 1.1.0

- When user pinches, line chart zooms in correctly. Next, user then swipes the chart horizontally, it moves correctly and reaches to last point of graph. But Now, when user tries to zoom out, the chart does not zoom out and appears to be stuck. However, if user swipes it to left and then tries to zoom out, graph correctly zoom out.

The question is: How can I allow user to zoom out when graph reaches any part of graph without needing user to swipe left/right?

Comment: did you provided zoom limits?

Comment: yes, we did provide zoom limits!